# Can I tweak window snapping shortcuts on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I use <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and friends to shuffle my windows on my two monitors a lot. However, I noticed that I also tweak windows position and size for 70/30 split very often. Windows' default 50/50 split does not work well for me.

I tried reading AutoHotKey documentation, it seems like it could be done, but I hope a ready-made solution already exists...

Is there any solution (software, autohotkey script, etc.) that lets me tweak how these very useful hotkeys behave? Ideally, I would like my ssh console to take 30% of my screen, IDE always 100%, browser 70%, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windowpad](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=21703) does just that.  It is a custom version of AutoHotKey specifically aimed at screen control.  It includes options to make each window snap to 50% or 25% of the screen, as well as snaping to 50% in the middle of the screen or 25% in each corner.

---

From the site:

**Features include:**

```
Move windows within the current monitor or between monitors (in multi-monitor setups).
Customize hotkeys via WindowPad.ini with AutoHotkey-like command syntax.
Define custom commands as labels or functions in WindowPad.ahk.
Execute WindowPad commands specified on the command-line.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) will do what you are looking for plus more.